# FreePBX can not connect to VM from Host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, host, freepbx

I was unable to Connect to my VM Admin Page interface from Host.

what should happen is that when the boots up it gives you and IP(verstion 6) address to write in your url bar like this one

*http://%5Bfe80::a00:27ff:fec6:8d75%5D/admin/config.php*

and this gives you the Admin page to be able to configure and set the state of the VM to active.

sadly this was not working and the web browser could not connect to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

SO my problem was in the Virtual Box settings. it did not allow the VM to connect.

I solved it by:

Open settings in Virtual Box -> Network -> Attached to and choose Bridge Adapter from drop down

also click on Advanced in the network tab.

then click on Promiscuous Mode and choose Allow all.

[image: View of settings in Virtual Box]